# Asynctask android

Tags: android, opencv

I want to run 2 method  simultaneously. However it show only the output of second method. Can you help me?

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Run1(); 
            Run2();

            return currentBitmap;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if(bitmap!=null) {

                loadImageToImageView();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: may I suggest simply running each set of code on separate threads?  You can use inline anonymous implementations of a thread for a clean implementation overall.

Answer (score 1):

Strategy depends on your tasks.

Don't use AsyncTask for simultaneous jobs, because by default it executed serially.

Your first try can be java Threads, if you don't need UI modification.

You can post results to UI thread by

- Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
- View.post(Runnable)
- View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

To process bitmap image consider to use [HandlerThread](https://youtu.be/adPLIAnx9og?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&t=90).

Comment: I tried thread but I used also bitmap image and I couldn't use thread in android

Answer (score 1):

> You can Use Two Seprate Threads

```
// Create two threads:

Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    Run1();
}
```

};

```
Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
public void run() {
  Run2();
}
```

};

```
// Start the both threads.
 thread1.start();
 thread2.start();

// Wait for them both to finish
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Always execute your async tasks on Thread pool

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Run1(); 
        Run2();

        return currentBitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if(bitmap!=null) {

            loadImageToImageView();
        }
    }
}.executeOnExecutors(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: yourAsyncTask what is that? Run1() and Run2() methods like above

Comment: Object of your async task

Comment: new AsyncTask<X, Y, Z> {

doInBackground() {
}
}.executeOnExecutors(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Run1(); 
        Run2();

        return currentBitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if(bitmap!=null) {

            loadImageToImageView();
        }
    }
}.executeOnExecutors(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: Should I change api, it intellisenses .executeOnExecutors(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) but then underline it.Field requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.os.AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Comment: Yes, you should if you want to run asnyc tasks in parallel.

Comment: @ P. Rai Its output only last method. Does not work first method run1()

Comment: There might be some other issue. Secondly create 2 asynctasks one for run1() and one for run2()

Comment: I created 2 asynctask and again first method does not work it run last method. Can I ask sth, run1(){...  Utils.matToBitmap(mGray, currentBitmap);} and run2(){...  Utils.matToBitmap(mGray, currentBitmap);} the problem is same bitmap?2 methods because return currentbitmap